# Send data from field outside a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have got the input field and some form, and I want add information from input field to data that sending in form. Is it possible if input field situated outside the form?

So the question: is it posible to get data from first form and append it to data in second form?

There are my forms:

```
<form name="phoneForm">
    Mobile phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
</form>

<form name="submitForm" method="POST" action="buy">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="parentNode.submit();"><%=j%></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%=Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_HALL%>" value="<%=hallId%>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%=Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_SEANCE%>" value="<%=seanceId%>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%=Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_ROW%>" value="<%=i%>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%=Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_PLACE%>" value="<%=j%>"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you put all hidden inputs in the first form and then submit the first form ?

Comment: Becouse second form is generating in loops 200 times. I use it in loop for creating square matrix

Comment: Actually it would be easier to put the phone field in the submitForm instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an extra hidden field in the submitForm. Copy the value of phoneForm.phone into that hidden field just before submitting the form.

```
<script>
function handleSubmit() {
    document.forms.submitForm.phone.value = document.forms.phoneForm.phone.value;
    document.forms.submitForm.submit();
}
</script>

<form name="phoneForm">
    Mobile phone: <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
</form>

<form name="submitForm" method="POST" action="buy">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="handleSubmit()"><%=j%></a>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%=Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_HALL%>" value="<%=hallId%>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%=Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_SEANCE%>" value="<%=seanceId%>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%=Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_ROW%>" value="<%=i%>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="<%=Consts.HTTP_REQUEST_PLACE%>" value="<%=j%>"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="phone" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do it please? I am not vary familiar with html and JS yet.

Comment: Was writing the answer on my phone just now, there you go!

Comment: I amended it so that clicking the anchor calls the handleSubmit() function instead, since form onsubmit requires the use of an <input type="submit"> rather than submitting the form by Javascript.

Comment: Now it add data, but broke other data. I use form in loop and when press for example on 20 it must send 20 but now it sent one by one from 1, evere click it increse +1
For example 1...2...3...4